# Border before text in QTextDocument

Tags: c++, css, qt, qtstylesheets, qtextdocument

I want to have an only left border around my text in QTextDocument
I think the required css for this will be

```
<div style='
  border-left: 6px solid red;
  background-color: lightgrey;
'> Hello World </div>
```

but lets say I have this qt code

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QWidget>
#include <QHBoxLayout>
#include <QTextEdit>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QWidget *widget = new QWidget();
    auto l = new QHBoxLayout(widget);
    widget->setLayout(l);
    QTextEdit *e = new QTextEdit(widget), *t = new QTextEdit(widget);
    l->addWidget(e);
    l->addWidget(t);

    QObject::connect(e, &QTextEdit::textChanged, [=]() {
        t->setHtml(e->toPlainText());
    });

    widget->show();
}
```

now if enter the html I got this output

[image: img]

but the correct and required output should be - 
[image]

I want the above output, is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately Qt rich text in `QTextDocument` doesn't support borders on anything except tables. And even then it is all borders at once, not individual sides.  https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/richtext-html-subset.html#css-properties

*UPDATE*: Well this reminds me of writing HTML for MSIE back in 1996, but hey there's (almost) always a way... (the only CSS in here is actually optional, the "required output" image doesn't have padding :).

[image]

```html
<!-- with width=100% the table extends all the way to the right margin -->
<table cellspacing=0 width='100%'>
<tr>
  <td width=6 bgcolor='red'/>
  <td bgcolor='lightgrey' 
      style='padding: 0 4px;'
    >Hello World</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

For example,

.h

```
#ifndef LEFTBORDERTEXTEDIT_H
#define LEFTBORDERTEXTEDIT_H

#include <QTextEdit>

class LeftBorderTextEdit : public QTextEdit
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    LeftBorderTextEdit();

    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent* e);

};

#endif // LEFTBORDERTEXTEDIT_H
```

.cpp

```
#include "LeftBorderTextEdit.h"
#include "qpainter.h"
#include <QTextBlock>
#include <QAbstractTextDocumentLayout>

LeftBorderTextEdit::LeftBorderTextEdit()
{

}


void LeftBorderTextEdit::paintEvent(QPaintEvent* e)
{

    QPainter p = QPainter(viewport());
    QPen pen = p.pen();
    QBrush brush = p.brush();
    pen.setBrush(QBrush(Qt::red, Qt::SolidPattern));
    brush.setColor(Qt::red);
    brush.setStyle(Qt::SolidPattern);
    p.setPen(pen);
    p.setBrush(brush);

    int bc = document()->blockCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < bc; i++)
    {
        qDebug() << i;
        QTextBlock block = document()->findBlockByNumber(i);
        QRectF bf = document()->documentLayout()->blockBoundingRect(block);
        bf = QRectF(bf.left() - 5, bf.top(), 5, bf.height());
        p.drawRect(bf);

    }
    p.end();
    QTextEdit::paintEvent(e);
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include "MainWindow.h"

#include <QApplication>
#include "LeftBorderTextEdit.h"


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    LeftBorderTextEdit t;
    w.setCentralWidget(&t);

    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```